# velocity macro .vm how to get URL/URI of current web page

Tags: url, velocity

Is there a simple way to get url/uri of the current page (page where values from the velocity macro will be displayed)?

for example 
I have got page http://abc.com/bb/cc.html

on this page there is a section (meta tags) which is constructed by bb.vm
I would like to add variable (tag) to bb.vm that will discover location of the page (http://abc.com/bb/cc.html) and then execute some logic using this variable.

Comment: ... Obviously, I meant what web framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Velocity Tools configured then the easiest way is:

```
$link.self
```